# Create Plotly Bar Chart with multiple y (offsetgroup) that has a dropdown that changes the data (dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, figure

I have a list of dataframes with the format

```
        date  pass  fail       rate  500  400  Blank Page
0 2023-07-18    31     5  13.888889    0    0           7
1 2023-07-19     2     0   0.000000    0    0           0
```

the dataframes are stored in a dict.

`dfDict = {'tagname1':df1, 'tagname2':df2 .... etc}`
the below code creates the exact plot I want for a single dataframe:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['fail'], name='Total Failures', text=df['fail'] ,marker_color = '#dd1616',offsetgroup=1 ), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['500'], name='5xx Error', text=df['500'] ,marker_color = '#00A3E0',offsetgroup=2 ), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['400'], name='4xx Error', text=df['400'] ,marker_color = '#43B02A',offsetgroup=3), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['Blank Page'], name='Blank Page', text=df['Blank Page'] ,marker_color = '#7f6000',offsetgroup=4), secondary_y=True)
            fig.update_layout(
            xaxis=dict(
                rangeselector=dict(
                    buttons=list([
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="1m",
                             step="month",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6,
                             label="6m",
                             step="month",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="YTD",
                             step="year",
                             stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="1y",
                             step="year",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all")
                    ])
                ),
                rangeslider=dict(
                    visible=True,
                    range=(startDate, endDate)
                ),
                type="date",
                range=(startDate, endDate)
            )
        )
```

the plot looks as such: [single dataframe plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWtj.png)

When i try to add a dropdown, the data keeps getting messed up. What am I doing wrong?

```
        df = self.errorDfs

        dropdownMenu = []
        for tag in self.errorDfs.keys():
            cleanTag = tag.replace("error", "")
            dropdownMenu.append({
                "label": cleanTag,
                "method": "update",
                "args": [{"visible": [tag == r for r in self.errorDfs.keys()]}],
            })
        for i, (label,df) in enumerate(df.items()):
            print(df)
            visibile = (i == 0)
            fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['fail'], name='Total Failures', text=df['fail'] ,marker_color = '#dd1616',offsetgroup=1 ), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['500'], name='5xx Error', text=df['500'] ,marker_color = '#00A3E0',offsetgroup=2 ), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['400'], name='4xx Error', text=df['400'] ,marker_color = '#43B02A',offsetgroup=3), secondary_y=True)
            fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df["date"], y=df['Blank Page'], name='Blank Page', text=df['Blank Page'] ,marker_color = '#7f6000',offsetgroup=4), secondary_y=True)
            fig.update_layout(
            xaxis=dict(
                rangeselector=dict(
                    buttons=list([
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="1m",
                             step="month",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=6,
                             label="6m",
                             step="month",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="YTD",
                             step="year",
                             stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=1,
                             label="1y",
                             step="year",
                             stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all")
                    ])
                ),
                rangeslider=dict(
                    visible=True,
                    range=(startDate, endDate)
                ),
                type="date",
                range=(startDate, endDate)
            )
        )
        fig.update_layout(
            updatemenus=[
                dict(
                    buttons=dropdownMenu,
                    direction="down",
                    pad={"r": 10, "t": 10},
                    showactive=True,
        
                    xanchor="left",

                    yanchor="top"
                ),
            ],
            title="Bar Chart with Dropdown",
            xaxis_title="Date",
            yaxis_title="Count",
        )
```

I am expecting a dropdown that allows me to switch the plot between dataframes